# Accessing item from LocalStorage (Angular 1.2)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, local-storage, ng-storage

I am running an old version of Angular - I have an object within my localStorage and I am trying to retrieve a single item from the object (rather than the whole the thing..)

```
var email = localStorage.user;
```

However the output of the localStorage.user variable is much longer (see below)- how would I retrieve the email address in this case 'bob@abc.com'?

```
{"firstname":"Bob","lastname":"Dole","id":"2000001999","accountId":"15","email":"bob@abc.com","instances":[{"name":"Test"}]}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LocalStorage values are always stored as `strings`. In order to refer to the `email` in the object, we need to convert it to a JSON. We can do that by parsing the string using [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method like below :

```
var email = JSON.parse(localstorage.user).email
```

Comment: @LukasLiesis : Lol :)

Answer (score 2):

You have Json structure not JS object, so parse it 1st

```
var email = JSON.parse(localStorage.user).email;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using html5 local storage we can store data, add expire time by using cookies and sessions. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41385990/6554634 go through that, gives a lot of explanation